# mySQL: Selecting data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I need help building a mysql query to select from multiple tables.
I have three database tables related to images: `images`, `tags`, `tag_asc`. I want to fetch an image data and its tag names by providing `image_id`.

For example, following is my tables structure:

**images:**

```
image_id    image_name     path       date   
1            test.jpg      dir       1311054433
```

**tags:**

```
tag_id      image_id
1             1
2             1
```

**tag_asc:**

```
tag_id      tag_name
1            "first"
2            "second"
3            "third"
```

I want to fetch the data of an image with `image_id = 1` from images table and all tag names associated with `image_id=1` from `tag_asc` table.

I'm using CodeIgniter Active records, but I just need idea of joining the tables.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from images i
left join tags t on t.image_id = i.image_id
left join tag_asc ta on ta.tag_id = t.tag_id
where i.image_id = 1;
```

Using `LEFT JOIN` means that rows will be returned even if there are no joining rows in the other tables (but you'll get `null` values in the columns for the missing rows), which is typically desirable.

If you want one row (not stated in question, but in comments), use this:

```
select i.image_id, group_concat(tag_name) as tag_names
from images i
left join tags t on t.image_id = i.image_id
left join tag_asc ta on ta.tag_id = t.tag_id
where i.image_id = 1
group by 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, but as i said 1 image can have multiple rows of tags in table tags (please see my example data). This query returns only one row from the tags table. For example see image_id 1 has two tags but it returns only 1. Can you tell me how to fix it? thanks.

Comment: I tested the query with your test data - query returned 2 rows.

Comment: @Bohemian, Thanks for your reply. Actually your first solution was exactly what I was looking for, but there was some problem in the while loop to fetch the results. Very sorry for that.

Comment: @ypercube what's wrong with "group by 1"? That syntax goes back to SQL92 standard.

Comment: @Bohemian: Nothing wrong with it. I was expecting `GROUP BY image_id`. I hadn't noticed the `where` restriction to one image only.

Comment: @ypercube dude - it would work even without the where. `GROUP BY` can take either the selected column number (ie 1,2,3 etc) in place of the actual column/value selected (eg id, substring(x, 1, 3), etc). This works with *all* databases going back forever.

Comment: @Bohemian: Yeah I know, i just don't use this feature so it sometimes confuses me when I see it (which usually is in ORDER BY).